# C# передать в гугл/яндекс карту массив адресов

Tags: c#, yandex-maps-api, google-maps-api

в базе есть адреса в каком то городе или регионе. можно ли передать массив этих адресов как GET параметр и чтобы карта показала метки по всем адресам?
типа
`Process.Start("https://www.google.ru/maps/place/"+adresses)`

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо обратиться к официальной документации карт Google или Yandex. Там подробно описываются данные вопросы.

Google Maps Static API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro

Yandex Maps Static API: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/staticapi/doc/1.x/dg/concepts/markers-docpage/

Ниже приведу пример запроса к яндекс API:

> https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?l=map&z=12&pt=37.582317,55.747788,comma~37.656479,55.774216,pm2rdm

Путь запроса:

`https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?l=map`

Параметры:

`z=12` - маштаб карты

`pt=` - метка или массив меток (через `~`)